# How to check if jQuery int variable has changed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently making a simple slider using jQuery, I'm only showing the first element of the `<ul>` with `.slice((slideIndex - 1), slideIndex)` where the variable `slideIndex` is equal to 1 by default.

I have a function that adds +1 to that value but the value doesn't to change.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vczq3te/)

This is what I tried, why is my variable not changing? How can I check if it has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your global variable did change in your function but you did not do anything about the visibility state of your `<li>`s. The `.hide()` and `.show()`functions where executed only once after the page loaded.

I prepared a little alternative script that hopefully does what you wanted:

Each time the button is clicked it does the following:

- it `.hide()`s all `<li>` elements in your jquery selection `$('#slider li')`,
- then it finds the `idx`-th `<li>` element and makes it visible again (`.show()`)
- while doing that it increments `idx` to the next value
- and finally the appended `.click()` triggers the first button click after loading.

The construct `(idx%len)` ensures that the `.eq()`-positions are limited to existing values.

```js
const ul=$('#slider li'),len=ul.length;

var idx=0;
$('#controlNext').click(ev=>ul.hide().eq((idx++)%len).show()).click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="controlNext">next</button>

<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>slide1</li>
    <li>slide2</li>
    <li>slide3</li>
    <li>slide4</li>
    <li>slide5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A slightly "cleaner" version of your script (fewer global constants and variables) would be the following:

```
const ul=$('#slider li');
ul.idx=0

$('#controlNext').click(ev=>ul.hide().eq((ul.idx++)%ul.length).show()).click()
```

`ul` is now the only global `const`, holding the jquery object with its `<li>`-collection inside. I then directly use its `.length` property and add an extra property `.idx` to it (instead of using a global variable).